# This error while editing my product in the backend

Tags: magento-1.9

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `index_event` (`type`, `entity`, `entity_pk`, `created_at`, `new_data`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, '2018-05-07 16:07:15', ?)

i am getting this error whenever i am trying to edit any product description?

how do i resolve and what does it mean
?